# What is the Maximum size Malloc function return at run-time?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-pool

**Question** 1:  what is the Maximum memory MALLOC can allocate?
**Question** 2:  Does Malloc allocate all the memory user had requested or just SUBSTANTIAL amount of memory.

I've tried to find the Dynamically Allocated memory size, but failed to do that.
And many people over stackoverflow have written, that you can't find the size of Dynamic Memory.**So is it true?**

I have tried these steps which is not correct for Dynamic memory Allocation.

```
int *var=malloc((sizeof(int)*10000));
printf("Size of Alloacted Memory=%ld ", (char *)(var+1) - (char *)var);
```

No error,but Output is incorrect.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It might help you understand why the code you have doesn't work if you also know that for any pointer (or array) `var` and index `i`, the expression `var[i]` is exactly equal to `*(var + i)`. That means what you're doing is really taking the size of a single element in you array (the difference between the second and first element in the memory allocate). In effect you're doing `&var[1] - &var[0]`.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? And no, there is non wa to find out what the maximum size of memory `malloc` can allocate. This is rather pointless BTW. Just call `malloc` with the amount of memory you need and if it returns `NULL`, then ylou know that memory couldn't be allocated and then act accordingly

Comment: Antti Haapala, instead of just putting comment and making score, just give attempt to read the Question.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused about what you exactly ask, so I try to answer as good as I can.

1. If you call `malloc()` with a given needed size, it will try to allocate that. If it succeeds, it returns you the address of the allocated memory block, if it fails, it returns `NULL`.

   Note that this refers only to virtual memory. On some systems, the physical memory is only provided when the memory is actually addressed, and if it then turns out that the request cannot be satisfied, the program is killed.
2. The size of the allocated chunk is whatever you requested. Actually, it might be a bit more for bookkeeping and padding, but that's none of your (the caller's) business - any access to a memory outside of what you are allowed to access is undefined behaviour and might result in malfunction.
3. <del>(I do not really understand where DMA comes in.)</del>

Addition about the "piecewise" allocation:

If you call `malloc()` in order to allocate a big memory chunk, the C library allocates this region of its virtual memory. If it is not in use yet, it has to be requested from the OS in one or other way.

Under Linux, this request will be granted as long as there is enough virtual memory (=address space) and certain other limits are fulfilled. Only as soon as you write to the allocated memory regions, they are actually allocated from the free portion of RAM. But for the practical use, this is irrelevant as the program acts "as-if" the allocation happened immediately (unless, there isn't as much memory available as assumed).

Comment: I think OP is using "DMA" as an unconventional abbreviation of "dynamic memory allocation". Nothing to do with its usual meaning of "direct memory access".

Comment: @IanAbbott Oh! Didn't think about that. Then it makes sense.

Comment: I mentioned DMA for Dynamic Memory Allocation. Actually one of my CS teacher told me that Malloc does not provide full requested memory to improve the performance of system and to save the physical memory from being preoccupied unnecessarily. It provide substantial amount from the requested quantity, and later append the memory region with more as-n-when required.  .

Comment: And that is the reason you can not find the size of dynamically allocate memory region. (What my teacher told me.) (If I am wrong please correct me.)

Comment: @srhaider As I already wrote: this is a specialty of some operating system, notably Linux, and not a feature of malloc() or the C library used. I'll extend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an upper bound binary search, trying values between `0` and `SIZE_MAX`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

_Bool try_alloc(size_t Val)
{
    void *p = malloc(Val);
    free(p);
    return !!p;
}
int main()
{

    printf("SIZE_MAX=%zu\n", SIZE_MAX);
    size_t it=0;
    size_t count=SIZE_MAX, step, first=0;
    while (count > 0) {
            it = first;
            step = count / 2;
            it += step;
            if (try_alloc(it)) {
                first = ++it;
                count -= step + 1;
            }
            else
                count = step;
    }
    printf("%zu\n", first); //found upper bound
    void *p; p= malloc(first-1); printf("test_alloc=%p\n", p); free(p);
}
```

Practically, a malloc implementation shouldn't let you allocate more than
`PTRDIFF_MAX`. See [Pascal Cuoq's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139746/pascal-cuoq) [A non-exhaustive list of ways C compilers break for objects larger than PTRDIFF_MAX bytes](https://trust-in-soft.com/objects-larger-than-ptrdiff_max-bytes/).